# Why only 35 of 758 links are indexed by Google in my sitemap.xml

Tags: search-engine-indexing

In the Google Webmasters Tool, there is a sitemap indexing status page:

There are **758** pages in my submitted `sitemap.xml` file, why only **35** of them are indexed? Is there any place that I can check the reason?

I have a homepage and a lot of subpages (those in the `sitemap.xml`). Home page is linking to those subpages. But they are not linking back (to home page). And those subpages are not inter-linked. I don't know whether that could be a possible reason.

[image]

Comment: This is a wild shot but are all the URLs in your sitemap http:// or https:// in line with the default for your site?

Comment: My site will redirect all HTTP traffic in a 301 to HTTPS traffic. Is that a good strategy? All the links in my sitemap.xml are started with HTTPS : `https://`

Comment: Yes that is correct, meaning that this is not the issue. Sorry, it was just something I have seen a few times with my clients.

Comment: Do you have a company link? Maybe we can be your client?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend again that he first step to take would be to search for your site in Google by doing a site:example.com search. This will show you how many URLs are being picked up by Google.

Also, in Search Console, check to see if it is highlighting any errors in the 'Issues' column below the graph in the screenshot to determine the exact issue.

Comment: Thanks, site:example.com returns a good number. And I do have some issues, please refer to this question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/102259/how-do-i-stop-those-weird-site-errors